# Is there a way to convert File from View?

Tags: android

Guys please help me about this. I just want to implement the `onTouch` method in listview to drag and drop a file.

I don't have enough reputation to show the error in an image form, but the error states that `Type mismatch: cannot convert from File to View`. Is there a way to convert this? tnx in advance

```
View x = mCurrentNode;
x.setOnTouchListener(new AdapterView.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { 

        if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){  
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);  
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);  
            return true;  
        }  

        return false;  

    }  
});
```

Comment: Edit your post to include a link to the image somewhere.

Comment: Yeah just use Imgur, but DON'T SURF THAT SITE!! imgur.com

Comment: Post the code that's throwing this error if you will.

Comment: @EdwardFalk sir I would like to show you the image but I dont have enough reputation to show it to you. Can I email the image ?

Comment: Just put the image on imgur or anywhere else you want, and include a link. One of us will edit your post once you do.

Comment: Oh, and more importantly, include your code.

Comment: Just add the logcat error here in text format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't. You should implement a view to represent the file. For example a textview with the name of the file.

Comment: sir, could you explain to me what you mean about "You should implement a view to represent the file"..

Comment: All things that are shown in the ui, are either a view, or drawn by a view. So if you want to display a file, you need a view. You already have a listview. If this listview shows a list of files and you want to drag them, drag the item of the listview. 

See this article on how to do this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the info sir, yes I've tried to implement that and it drags the entire listview. I just only want to drag file or a folder not the whole listview.

Comment: Have you tried the example on the website, it drags the cells of the list. You can also take a look at this, but it is dragging individual views, not items in a list: http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

Comment: Yes, I've tried the example but still it is not applicable for what I meant . :<